# python pandas add rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an initial data frame with only one row:

```
A     B     C     D     E   
0     1     5    11     0
```

I want to add rows that only differs from the initial row by adding one in one column. For example, after adding the second row, the data frame will be:

```
A     B     C     D     E     
0     1     5    11     0     
1     1     5    11     0
```

After adding five rows:

```
A     B     C     D     E     
0     1     5    11     0      
1     1     5    11     0     
0     2     5    11     0    
0     1     6    11     0  
0     1     5    12     0 
0     1     5    11     1
```

Any idea how to do this with a for loop by indicating column index? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: These are all indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 5x5 identity matrix and add it to the first row, then append it to the original DataFrame:

```
df.append(df.loc[0] + pd.DataFrame(np.eye(5, dtype='int'), columns=df.columns))
Out: 
   A  B  C   D  E
0  0  1  5  11  0
0  1  1  5  11  0
1  0  2  5  11  0
2  0  1  6  11  0
3  0  1  5  12  0
4  0  1  5  11  1
```